# how to get axios.get data and where to put it in redux reducer initial state

Tags: reactjs, redux, axios, json-server

I am trying to get `json` `array` data from `json-server @port 3001`, I want this data to put in initial state of my reducer in the form of `array`. Basically it's a CRUD app of `redux`. I think I am not using the correct syntax.

This is backend data in `json` database.

```js
{
    "posts": [
        {
            "id": "2019-10-14T07:47:34.044Z",
            "title": "Shani",
            "message": "KHRP",
            "edititng": false
        },
        {
            "id": "2019-10-14T07:50:03.954Z",
            "title": "Shani",
            "message": "KHRPUR",
            "edititng": false
        },
        {
            "id": "2019-10-14T16:19:55.551Z",
            "title": "Sherry",
            "message": "BWP",
            "edititng": false
        }
    ]
}
```

```js
const postReducer = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_POST':
            return state.concat([action.data]);
        case 'DELETE_POST':
            return state.filter((post) => post.id !== action.id);
        case 'EDIT_POST':
            return state.map((post) => post.id === action.id ? {
                ...post,
                editing: !post.editing
            } : post);
```

```js
// I can add post with just.
axios.post('/posts', data) 
// in my ADD_POST action.
```

But when I try to get all my posts on my AllPost page with `axios.get('/posts', params)` and many other methods I tried but I could not get the data. 
One more thing I wanted to ask that should I get json data and pass it to  store directly? If yes then how..

Comment: can you add actions to the question?

Answer (score 1):

types.js

```
export const ADD_POST= 'ADD_POST';
```

action.js

```
import * as types from './types';

const setDocumentData = data => ({
  type: types.ADD_POST,
  data,
});

export const setData = details => dispatch => {
  dispatch(setDocumentData(details));
};
```

reducer.js

```
import * as types from 'store/actions/types';

const initialState = {
  application: {},
};

const Application = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case types.ADD_POST:
      let setOldData = {...state.application};
      setOldData = action.details;

      return {
        ...state,
        application: setOldData,
      };

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```